# How to check the unix time is 1 day older

Tags: perl, bash

How to check the UNIX time is 1 day older

for ex : UNIX time is 1308715355

I want to find that that time 1 day older or not with now

Comment: older than what? that now? just compute the current timestamp, take the difference, convert from seconds to hours... etc

Comment: I want to older than with now

Comment: When you say "older" do you mean the day after or the day before? If its July 25th is July 24th or July 26th "older"? And do you define "1 day older" as 24 hours or 1 calendar day? Is 11pm on July 25th "1 day older" than 2am on July 26th or does it have to go all the way to 11pm on July 26th? (Your question makes a fantastic interview question to see how the candidate works ambiguous requirements)

Comment: @Schwern, Something older is something that has been around longer. A timestamp of July 24th is older than a timestamp of July 25th. That's not ambiguous. I agree that "day older" can be ambiguous, which is why I handled both in my answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you consider 2011-06-27T01:05 to be less than one day older than 2011-06-28T01:00,

```
use DateTime;

my $epoch = '1308715355';

my $dt_ref = DateTime->from_epoch(epoch => $epoch, time_zone => 'local');
my $dt_now = DateTime->now(time_zone => 'local');

$dt_ref->add(days => 1);
if ($dt_ref <= $dt_now) {
   # At least one day old.
}
```

If you consider 2011-06-27 to be one day older than 2011-06-28 regardless of times of day,

```
use DateTime;

my $epoch = '1308715355';

my $dt_ref = DateTime->from_epoch(epoch => $epoch, time_zone => 'local')
   ->truncate( to => 'days' );
my $dt_now = DateTime->today(time_zone => 'local');

$dt_ref->add(days => 1);
if ($dt_ref <= $dt_now) {
   # At least one day old.
}
```

**Upd**: Grammar error fix: s/older/older than/

Answer (score 4):

```
> date -dtomorrow +%s; date +%s
1309366474
1309280074
```

This should handle, BTW, the DST problem that evan mentioned.

You didn't mention your desired solution space, so hopefully this would suffice.

Answer (score 2):

Comparing with the number of seconds for a day is generally adequate (60 * 60 * 24 = 86400).  However, if this always needs to work exactly, you need to take into account when you switch to and from DST.  Those days are 23 & 25 hours.

Most people tend to overlook daylight savings time.  This can cause a lot of issues if you need precision when dealing with time.

Answer (score 2):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use DateTime;

my $epoch = '1308715355';

my $dt = DateTime->from_epoch(epoch => $epoch, time_zone => 'local')
                 ->add(days => 1);
print $dt; # '2011-06-22T23:02:35' -- for *my* time zone (CDT)
print $dt->epoch; # '1308801755'
```